# Date formatting in javascript with bad format

Tags: javascript, date, format

I want to format a date, which has a bad format.

For example:

> Mar 8, 2019 5:13pm GMT+0100

It would work, if it would've the following format:

> Mar 8, 2019 17:13:00 GMT+0100

Is there any way to format the date quickly, so it can be parsed by the default javascript Date function?

I tried to find the substr by pm/am. But I don't know how to get the rest of it(5:13pm) and also how to format it "automatically". I thought about adding 12, but I am not sure how to grab the substring.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

As for now I wsa using momentJs, but this is not working either.

```
function returnFormatedDate(dt)
{
    return moment(dt).format('DD.MM.YY HH:mm');
};
```

Returns "invalid date"

Edit2: 
Example code but I prefer Chris G.'s one:

```js
var str = "Mar 8, 2019 5:13pm GMT+0100";
var parts = str.split(" ");
console.log(parts);
if(3 in parts)
{
  badPart = parts[3];
  
  if(badPart.includes("pm"))
  {
    var newBadPart = badPart.replace('pm', '');
    var moddedDate = newBadPart.split(":");
    moddedDate[0] = 12 + Number(moddedDate[0]);
    badPart = moddedDate.join(":");
  }
  else if(badPart.includes("am"))
  {
   badPart.replace("am", ""); 
  }
  var newParts = [parts[0], parts[1], parts[2], badPart, parts[4]];
  var dte = new Date(newParts.join(" "));
  console.log(dte);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you put up the code that you tried?

Comment: Try using momentJS.

Comment: Edited my inital post.

Comment: Start with `var parts = dt.split(" ");` The bad time is now in `parts[3]`.

Comment: Here's example code: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/2esxhyqb/

Comment: Thank you very much. Added mine above, but I am pretty sure yours is better.

Comment: Check out here https://jsfiddle.net/x9pLhqon/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution:

```js
var str = "Mar 8, 2019 5:13pm GMT+0100";
var parts = str.split(" ");
console.log(parts);
if(3 in parts)
{
  badPart = parts[3];
  
  if(badPart.includes("pm"))
  {
    var newBadPart = badPart.replace('pm', '');
    var moddedDate = newBadPart.split(":");
    moddedDate[0] = 12 + Number(moddedDate[0]);
    badPart = moddedDate.join(":");
  }
  else if(badPart.includes("am"))
  {
   badPart.replace("am", ""); 
  }
  var newParts = [parts[0], parts[1], parts[2], badPart, parts[4]];
  var dte = new Date(newParts.join(" "));
  console.log(dte);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And this is Chris G's, which I prefere more:
 https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/2esxhyqb

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```js
var timestamp = "Mar 8, 2019 5:13pm GMT+0100";

var cur_date = timestamp.replace(/T/, ' ').replace(/\..+/, '').substr(0, 19);
console.log(cur_date)
```

Comment: This wont work: https://jsfiddle.net/qb0xrck9/1/ 
I had to remove pm/am and convert it to valid time, in case its pm.
Thank you anyway